# "Papa-anjo" - persona en una relación con alguien más joven

Tags: vocabulario, portugués

En Brasil, se les dice chistosamente *papa-anjos* (literalmente "*comeángeles*") a los que salen con alguien perceptiblemente más joven e inmaduro, especialmente en escuelas.

Por ejemplo, un pibe de 16 años que sale con una nena de 13 sería un *papa-anjo*.

¿Como dirían en castellano?

Answer (score 6):

Lo normal, al menos en mi zona, es llamarlos «**asaltacunas**», sobre todo cuando uno de los dos es menor de edad.

[En el DLE no aparece](http://dle.rae.es/?w=asaltacunas), pero sí aparece por ejemplo en el diccionario español - inglés de Oxford:

> **[asaltacunas](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/traducir/espanol-ingles/asaltacunas)**
>   *[cradle-robber](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/cradle-robber), n.*
>
> *<sup>SUSTANTIVO MASCULINO Y FEMENINO.</sup>
>
>   México
>
>   coloquial*
>
> 1 cradle-robber *EEUU coloquial*
>   cradle-snatcher *Británico coloquial*

Si lo buscas en Google puedes encontrar muchas más fuentes.
La verdad es que me ha sorprendido ver que en casi todos lados lo ponen como coloquialismo latinoamericano, porque yo lo llevo escuchando desde bien pequeño en España. Pero bueno, aquí va un [ejemplo de uso en un medio español](http://www.semana.com/amp/asaltacunas-seccion-gente-edicion-1552-jan-28-2012/252598).

Comment: También "robacunas": http://untref.edu.ar/diccionario/buscar.php?q=463&p=robacunas